# Google AI platform for inference, what is supported?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I have been reading over the docs for Google AI platform for inference, they do not seem (maybe I have missed it) to state what frameworks are supported.

Am I to assume that all frameworks are supported?

The training side supports custom dockers, which gives the feeling that any code will run as long as you can package it in a container - but on the prediction / inference product there is no such guidance.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom prediction routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines) is a feature already in place the lets you perform your predictions with any custom code, from any framework of your choice. Bear in mind that it is still in beta but you can already try it.

Comment: Thanks @Javier Bobeda, what are the key benefits over using K8s?

Comment: It is easier to use and you don't have to worry about the architecture behind it. I t will also scale up automatically when you perform more requests. Here you have [an article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/should-google-be-your-ai-and-machine-learning-platform/) about it.